# Adding つき to the end of nouns

Tags: grammar, suffixes

> 湯ぶねに体を沈めると、どばーっと色つきのお湯があふれた。
>   When he sank his body into the bath, the coloured hot water gushed over.

I took me a while to figure out that 色つき meant 'coloured'. It isn't in the bi-lingual dictionaries. Is it a single word or am I missing a grammar point where I can add つき to the end of a word to turn it into an "-ed" word?

For example if I wanted to talk about the "whitened paper" i.e. paper that has been made white, could I say 白つきの紙?

Basically, if つき does work as a suffix when/how should I use it?

Comment: I'm guessing it is a compound usage of 付く, but not 100% sure.

Comment: JDIC has an entry for 付き marked (used as noun suffix) meaning "attached, furnished with, having such an appearance", so seems safe to say it works as a suffix and has a somewhat wide range of usage.  Hopefully an answer will give a more concrete idea of that range.

Comment: Apparently paper is made white by [decreasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleaching_of_wood_pulp) the color of the wood pulp? So 付き wouldn't make sense I think. But with water it works because I imagine they add some sort of ingredient to it.

Comment: I don't come up other added 付き words in colour except 色付き. We usually say 赤い紙, 赤の紙 and 赤色の紙.

Comment: @YuuichiTam Paper was just an example. I'm interested in how to use つき more generally. But now I'm wondering what 赤い紙 is? When would paper be red?

Comment: @user3856370 ～付き is common. For example, プール付きの家、おまけ付きのお菓子,サイン付きの色紙 etc. And red paper is just an example but there are various coloured papers in Japan like 折り紙.

Comment: 白つきの紙 sounds like a paper in a color other than white with a white spot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

「つき」is a suffix to a noun, meaning "attached, accompanied with, affected," for example:

> ひも付き - a string attached
>
> 条件付き - condition attached, conditional
>
> 期限付き - with a time-limit
>
> 賞味期限付き - with a pull-date stipulated
>
> [曰]{いわ}くつき(の品) - sth with an odd story behind it
>
> 昼食（弁当）付き - a lunch included (in a day-trip fare)
>
> 三食付きの宿 - an inn that offers three meals a day
>
> 三食昼寝付きの亭主 - a common saying of an idle and spoiled husband who is furnished with three free meals everyday and a privilege of taking a daily nap.
>
> [瘤]{こぶ}付き - a man or woman with a big lump on his / her back, meaning a divorced man or woman accompanied with a dependent (child / parent).
>
> 景品付き - a premium attached
>
> 電動機付き a motor attached, or a motor-driven

色付き means 'colored.' Sometimes it means "biased to sth." or "have something to do with an influential factor."「その金は色付きだ」 means "the money in question has a string attached."

白(赤、黒、緑、黄, whatever color)付きの色 doesn't make sense.

Appendix:

Also there is a word, 「[憑]{つ}き」 to be pronounced same as 付き. It means "affected or controlled by a demon or a mysterious spirit of evil animals." [狐]{キツネ}[憑]{つ}きの男（女） means a mad man / woman controlled by the evil spirit of a cunning fox.

Comment: What is this "sth with a story behind"

Comment: @kyloRen. 'sth' is an abbreviation of something.

Comment: might be worth adding furigana to 曰くつき since it is a very unusual reading （いわ）

Comment: By "viased to sth", did you mean "biased by sth"?

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I added 振り仮名 to 曰く, and corrected a typo for 'bias,' and added the usage of キツネ憑き though it's irrelevant to 「色付き」just for your amusement.