# What's the meaning of までついて?

Tags: meaning

The までついて in the following paragraph is presenting some difficulties to me, especially the ついて, which I'm not sure is the て-form of つく or is conjunction ついて(就いて).

だけど、この１月号のすばる脳のすばるはいつも以上に可愛くて可愛くて仕方なく、しかも付録までついてこれは買うしかない！！ ([source](http://ameblo.jp/kumarock-aki/entry-11437714570.html))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, this question is highly related to the recent question:

[Adding つき to the end of nouns](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/35667/adding-%e3%81%a4%e3%81%8d-to-the-end-of-nouns)

「つく」＝「付く」 (「就く」 has nothing to do with it.)

「つく」, in this context, means "***to come with***"

「まで」, of course, means "***even***".

「[付録]{ふろく}」 means a "***freebie/present*** that automatically comes with the purchase of  a book/magazine" in this context.  (The kanji 「付」 is in it; It's all in the name.)

Thus, the sentence is saying that the January issue of this magazine "***even comes with a present***, so you have no choice but to buy a copy!".

(In case you did not know, some Japanese magazines come with pretty good free presents and quite a few people buy those magazines for the presents rather than for the magazines themselves.)

[Below] If you could get that cool-looking tote free for buying a copy of the magazine, would you be able to resist it?  I would not be!

[image]
<sub>(source: [seesaa.net](http://tubenojyouhou.up.n.seesaa.net/tubenojyouhou/image/P1000075.JPG?d=a81))</sub>

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea 付録 could be used that way.  JDIC and 国語辞書 (via goo) searches don't seem to explicitly include that usage, but I can definitely see a possible connection between the "appendix/supplement" meaning and "freebie" now that I think about it.

Comment: Nevermind, 国語辞書 (2) applies, it is just not explicit about the "attached thing" being intended as a gift/present.  Sorry for the noise.